# How can I find out what is the provisioned read/write capacity for a On-demand capacity dyanmodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I create a dynamodb table with On-demand capacity mode. I can use `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` and `ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits` metrics to view consumed unites of the table or GSI. But how can I know what the capacity the table is provisioned at a given time?

Comment: I presume that DynamoDB On-Demand does _not_ use provisioned capacity. Or, if it does, it rapidly changes it based on demand. See: [Amazon DynamoDB On-Demand – No Capacity Planning and Pay-Per-Request Pricing | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-on-demand-no-capacity-planning-and-pay-per-request-pricing/)

Comment: I believe it rapidly change. What I am asking is how I can know what is provisioned by On Demond at a given time?

Comment: May I ask why do you need such information? The whole premise of on-demand capacity is that you don't need to think about it. [However, there is a default soft limit of 40k RCU/WCU per table even with on-demand capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#default-limits-throughput-capacity-modes).

Comment: The reason is that I'd like to analysis the cost and compare it with provisioned solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between **on-demand** pricing and **auto-scaling**:

In **on-demand**, you pay per request, and there is no "provisioned capacity" at all - in theory (although perhaps not guaranteed in practice) your workload can do 10 requests a second one minute, and 10,000 a second in the next minute. In **auto-scaling**, there is a provisioned capacity for which you pay, but DynamoDB helps you by periodically figuring out the "best" provisioned capacity - something only slightly higher than your current needs.

Amazon have a [nice blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-auto-scaling-performance-and-cost-optimization-at-any-scale/) explaining the two features - on-demand (with no provisioned capacity) and auto-scaling (changing the provisioned capacity automatically) - and how they can even be combined to reduce your bills.

Comment: I think on-demand is to provision automatically based on the traffic over the last 30 minutes. In other words, on-demand hide the provision from developers. Based on this doc https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/, the initial WCU is 4000 and 12000 RCU. What I am asking is how do I know the WCU/RCU from on-demand mode